# R Markdown, ##Null appearing under my chart grid

Tags: r, ggplot2, r-markdown

I'm having an issue with a ##Null showing up under my chart grid. The charts are displaying perfectly. Below is the code, I used the same sample data for each graph because that aspect is important.

````
```{r include=TRUE, echo=FALSE, message=FALSE, warning=FALSE, fig.height=4.5, fig.width=10}
library(ggplot2)
ch1 <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(mpg, wgt)) +
       geom_point(shape=22, size=3.5)  + 
       geom_smooth(method=lm, se=FALSE + 
       ggtitle ("Selected 1-5Y Offerings by Maturity")

ch2 <-ggplot(mtcars, aes(mpg, wgt)) +
      geom_point(shape=1) +
      geom_smooth(method=lm) + 
      ggtitle("All Offerings 1-5Y")

      multiplot(ch1,ch2, cols=2)
```
````

I also put the 'multiplot' link to the code below if anyone wanted to know what that was. 
http://www.cookbook-r.com/Graphs/Multiple_graphs_on_one_page_(ggplot2)/

**Any ideas on how to get rid of the ##NULL in the RMarkdown HTML output that shows up as if its not properly returning something...

**********SOLVED**********
all you have to do is results='hide'. It will take it away.

Comment: try adding either your actual data or some dummy data to make this a reproducible issue.

Comment: do you need the parentheses around multiplot()?

Comment: added dummy data to make reproducible. I deleted the (). That was an error from messing around with nesting the code elsewhere. It had no bearing.

Comment: solved. All you do is add results='hide' to the code chunk options and it works.

Comment: If you set results='hide' for the full document, then rendered tables (output="asis") disappear. The NULL comes from printing the value of the last expression, i.e., the return value of multiplot(). If you assign this to an (unused) variable, nothing will print (just as happens at the R console): `not_used <- multiplot(...)`

Answer (score 4):

Add results='hide' to the code chunk options and it will take away ##NULL, or any results for that matter. code below:

````
```{r include=TRUE, echo=FALSE, results='hide' message=FALSE, warning=FALSE, fig.height=4.5, fig.width=10}

library(ggplot2)
    ch1 <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(mpg, wgt)) +
           geom_point(shape=22, size=3.5)  + 
           geom_smooth(method=lm, se=FALSE + 
           ggtitle ("Selected 1-5Y Offerings by Maturity")

    ch2 <-ggplot(mtcars, aes(mpg, wgt)) +
          geom_point(shape=1) +
          geom_smooth(method=lm) + 
          ggtitle("All Offerings 1-5Y")

      multiplot(ch1,ch2, cols=2)
```
````