# Hiding null output

Tags: r, null, hide, scatter-plot, ioslides

I am trying to make an ioslides presentation with the scatter graphs on one slide. However I am getting these null outputs and they are pushing the scatter graphs off of my slides.

My code and the null outputs:
[image: My code and the null outputs]

I have sliced all rows with `na` values as I thought that may be the problem but it didn't work. I also used the `is.null` function and all three datasets came back false. I just want to hide the null output.

Comment: Try wrapping the plot in the invisible function, like `invisible(plot(...))`

Comment: Since this is about R Markdown, try adding  `results='hide'` to the block header - https://stackoverflow.com/q/45380179/10276092

Comment: thank you so much! it worked! been trying to get rid of it for weeks!

Comment: Your code uses base graphics (`plot()`) and tries to add `ggplot2` modifications (`geom_smooth()`).  That won't work.  Stick with one system or the other.